# Normalizing distance between <LI> inner text and bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists, normalization

Recently noticed that Chrome and Safari have different default distance between text inside `<li>` and the bullet when `list-style-position` is set to `inside`:

[image][image]

**The question is:** how to normalize that distance to something equal in both browsers without using `background-image` technique which is very ugly?

Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit),
Safari version 10.0 (11602.1.50.0.10)

*PS. Code of list from screenshots:*

```
ul { list-style-position: inside; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul > li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: With Firefox yet another ... why do you need to use `inside`?

Comment: To me looks the same on all browsers ... chrome/safari/firefox on MAC https://jsfiddle.net/j0vopgfo/

Comment: @LGSon to set this `<ul>` to a one line with form input vertically

Comment: @DaniP the distance is different in chrome and safari - http://take.ms/8IirT

Comment: Maybe you want to include the versions [I can't replicate the issue](https://postimg.org/image/m84vb82rn/)

Comment: @DaniP ok, I'll include versions into question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a solution/reason why Safari misbehave (or it is Chrome), you could use a pseudo element as a workaround

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li::before {
    content: '•';
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that a good solution, but I'll wait for another ideas. May be somebody knows origin of that bug.

Answer (score 2):

Following on @LGSon answer, I would recommend using the `counter()` CSS function with the optional parameter of `list-style-type`.

You can use the `disc` value, but there's a little bit more flexibility. (*See playground below*).

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: list-item;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-increment: list-item;
}
ul li::before {
  content: counter(list-item, disc);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

### PLAYGROUND:

```
decimal-leading-zero
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: list-item;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-increment: list-item;
}
ul li::before {
  content: counter(list-item, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

```
lower-roman
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: list-item;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-increment: list-item;
}
ul li::before {
  content: counter(list-item, lower-roman);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

---

Accepted values:

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/EN/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

> disc, circle, square, decimal, decimal-leading-zero, lower-roman,
>   upper-roman, lower-greek, lower-latin, upper-latin, armenian,
>   georgian, lower-alpha, upper-alpha

---

### MORE INFO:

More info on CSS `counter()` function **[here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/counters/)**.

Comment: Going to be a nice and cross-browser(surprisingly for me) solution according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters). Thanks!

Comment: CSS `counter()` function has been there since `2.1` and it is quite nice, but it's one of those things that people need to look back into to actually remember how they are used.

Comment: When I saw it first time I thought that this is one of new CSS3 features on a one line with `calc` and etc. :)

Comment: You can even do [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/asobttsc/) with the `counters()` one `;-)`.